# How do you implement this when else statement in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have the following example from an answer on a previous post on Stackexchange Electrical Engineering:

```
show_out   <= show  when player = '0' else '0';
set_out    <= set   when player = '0' else '0';
input_out  <= input when player = '0' else "00000000";
-- etc.

show_out2  <= show  when player = '1' else '0';
set_out2   <= set   when player = '1' else '0';
input_out2 <= input when player = '1' else "00000000";
-- etc.
```

I want to insert it in a process like the one below:

```
architecture Behavioral of twoplayermux1 is
begin
    process (show,set,input,try,player)
    begin

-- INSERT THE LINES OF WHEN ELSE ASSIGNMENTS HERE...

    end process twoplayermux1;
end Behavioral;
```

How does the syntax looks like for that?

Comment: Just replace it with set of if ...else.. endif. (Why do you insists on using a process?)

Comment: I saw your previous post. I think what you are having a problem with is that you are assigning different outputs in each case. So you need to assign both show_out and show_out2 in all your separate cases. The way you have written it, the synthesizer will set show_out = show and show_out2 = show permanently.

Comment: @user110971
What about two different if statements in-between "begin" and "end process twoplayermux1"?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is the same whether inside or outside a process using VHDL-2008. The example slide below shows the syntax. Source for image is: [enter link description here](http://www.synthworks.com/papers/VHDL_2008_end_of_verbosity_2013.pdf). As mentioned in the comment on your question, there's no real need for the process.

[image]

Comment: There's also the [`case`-statement](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00014.htm)

Comment: Note that some synthesis tools (including Vivado) don't support `when` statements in processes.

Comment: @CalebReister have you tried specifying VHDL 2008 type in Vivado? I have certainly synthesized this syntax in Vivado. Perhaps it also depends on your Vivado version. It works in Vivado 2018.3.

Comment: @user_007 Yes I did, but I would have been using Vivado 2017.4 when I last tried it.

Comment: +1 for end of vhdl verbosity link.